# Botão marcar/Desmarcar caixa de seleção

Tags: c#, winforms

Em meu programa tem um botão para marcar e o mesmo botão para desmarcar uma caixa de seleção.

Exemplo: Se eu clicar uma vez, ele marca a caixa de seleção, se eu clicar novamente no botão ele desmarca a caixa de seleção. Porém, se clicar novamente já não marca mais a caixa de seleção, depois do segundo clique o botão perde a ação.

Segue meu código:

```
public frmLaudosPS()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.btn_seleciona.Click += this.marcar;
}

private void marcar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = (DataTable)dgw_laudos.DataSource;
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        row["SELECIONAR"] = true;
    this.btn_seleciona.Click -= this.marcar;
    this.btn_seleciona.Click += this.desmarcar;
}

private void desmarcar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = (DataTable)dgw_laudos.DataSource;
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        row["SELECIONAR"] = false;
}
```

Comment: Falta o código do `desmarcar`. Sem ele é impossível ajudar sem que seja na base do chute.

Comment: Desculpe tinha me esquecido do restante do código, já coloquei o restante do código. Vlw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Falta você remover e adicionar o *handler* no evento de desmarcar também. Sem isso o código não faz sentido.

```
private void desmarcar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = (DataTable)dgw_laudos.DataSource;
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        row["SELECIONAR"] = false;

    this.btn_seleciona.Click -= this.desmarcar;
    this.btn_seleciona.Click += this.marcar;
}
```

De qualquer forma, eu acho que seria muito mais interessante você manter apenas um método. Não faz sentido manter o mesmo código duas vezes apenas para mudar o valor de um *booleano*.

```
private void marcar_desmarcar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = (DataTable)dgw_laudos.DataSource;
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        row["SELECIONAR"] = !Convert.ToBoolean(row["SELECIONAR"]);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Linq, mas porque o botão perde a ação após o segundo clique ou seja após desmrcar...

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro Você viu a resposta?

Comment: Sim vi sim e ja ajustei o codigo e mesmo assim, quando eu clico pela terceira vez o botão não faz mais nada..

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro Daqui a pouco faço um teste e vejo se isso ocorre mesmo

Comment: Vlw Obrigado Linq...

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro Ajustei a resposta com outra alternativa, ainda não consegui fazer o teste com os handlers

Comment: Muito obrigado Linq deu certinho sua alteração, deixei um único método.